# Java - How to add an element to a DefaultListModel between other two?

Tags: java, jlist

Here is it:

```
btnInsertL.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            String textField1Content = textField1.getText();
            if (textField1.getText().contains("Nova Categoria")) {
            } else {
                modelL.addElement(textField1Content);
            }
        }
    });
```

Obviously, when I click in this "btnInsertL", it adds to my list a new element according to the name of the textField1. But with this, we have a subtle problem if we want the process to be more "dynamic":

It always add the new element to the END of the list, ignoring the selection. How could I add a new element according to the element that is already selected? I suppose this involves element-indexes of the DefaultListModel.

```
Element 1
Element 2
Element 3
```

Let us suppose that the "Element 2" is selected. When I click in the "btnInsertL", I want that the FOURTH element goes between the element 2 and the element 3.

Well, I think that this question is not that useless, I hope it helps someone too. I thank you all very much for the attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You checked the JavaDocs right?

Take a look at [`DefaultListModel.add(int, E)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html#add%28int,%20E%29)

Comment: Thank you very much! Sorry, beginner mistakes :). I'll answer down the answer to my code and then give you the right answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check the `DefaultListModel.add(int, E)` and use the `getSource()` method of the ActionEvent to see which button was selected.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the MadProgrammer I found the answer:

```
btnInsertL.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            String textField1Content = textField1.getText();
            if (textField1.getText().contains("Nova Categoria")) {
            } else {
                modelL.add(listL.getSelectedIndex() + 1,textField1Content);
            }
        }
    });
```

Problem more than solved! :).